# Triggering an action by NSMenuItem

Tags: swift, nsmenuitem

Is it possible to trigger an action that is not associated with any ViewController by clicking NSMenuItem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible! Use `target` on property on [NSMenuItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMenuItem/target) like this:

```
var newItem : NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: Selector("Quit:"), keyEquivalent: "")
newItem.target = // Your Target
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that it has a `target` property.  Docs: "An object to be the target of action messages sent by the receiver."

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, yes it is. You just have to use @selector with the associated function, so that when you click the NSMenuItem the function will be call. Here is an example:

```
[self.statusBarMenu addItem:[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Menu Item" action:@selector(doSomething) keyEquivalent:@"D"]];
```